# Confused about functional composition in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, composition

I know that `(.) f g x = f (g x)`. Suppose `f` has type `Int -> Int`, `g` has type `Int -> Int -> Int`. Now let `h` be defined by `h x y = f (g x y).` Which of the following statements are true and why (why not)?

a. `h = f . g`

b. `h x = f . (g x)`

c. `h x y = (f . g) x y`

Supposedly, only b. is true, while the others are false. I would think a. and b. are equivalent... a. is saying two functions are equal. Two functions are equal only iff when I add an argument to the end of both sides, it will still be equal. So I get `h x = f . g x`. Now `(.)` is an operator, so functional application takes precedence over it, so `f . g x = f . (g x)`, which is b.

Comment: Am I missing something? If `g` has type `Int->Int->Int`, then `g x` has type `Int->Int`, and `f (g x)` is a type error.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `h` is defined by `h x y = f (g x y)`?

Comment: BTW, welcome to stack overflow! It often helps if you hang around for a while after asking to respond to comments, since it speeds things up. Admittedly we've not been terribly quick to respond this time.

Comment: Assuming that `h x y = (g x y)` you can be a punk on your homework and write in the "better answer" `h = ((.) . (.)) f g`

Comment: If `h = f . g` then `h x = (f . g) x` not `h x = f . g x`.

Comment: Yes, I did mean that... Sorry guys.

Comment: no, a. and c. are equivalent by "eta reduction": (f x = g x <==> f = g). This means that both `f x = g x` and `f = g` are equally _a._ correct; _b._ incorrect; _c._ make no sense. And of course `f x y = g x y` is the same as `f x = g x` by the same measure.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a homework, so I won't give the answer of which one is correct.

You consider `a` and `b` as identical incorrectly. If `f . g` is applied to `x`, you get (from the definition of `(.)`)

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

But `b` is `f . (g x)`, which doesn't expand to `f (g x)`. If you follow `b` through using the definition of `(.)`, you will see the sense in the comments of the others.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, thank you. So my current understanding is as follows [is it correct?]:


(A) is true iff `h x = (f . g) x`, which is `f (g x)`. That is incorrectly typed, because `g x :: Int -> Int` but `f` needs `Int` as an input.

(B) They are both functions `Int -> Int`, so b. is true iff `h x y = (f . (g x)) y`, that is by defn. of funcl. compn. `f (g x y)`, which is `h x y`. So this is true.

(C) `h x y = (f . g) x y = f (g x) `y, which is incorrectly typed for the same reason as a.

If thse explanations are correct, we can post it as an answer to my question. :)

Comment: @DominikTeiml to decide whether expA = expB, we first need to see whether either of the expressions is *well-formed*, which in Haskell means "has a type". If I write `head head`, this expression has no type, i.e. is ill-formed. gven the types for `f` and `g`, the expression `f . g` is ... ill-formed? well-formed? (choose the correct answer).

Comment: @DominikTeiml The corrected question has `h x y = f (g x y)`, so `b` is true.

Comment: @WillNess Ill-formed, because the input of `f` is `Int`, but `g :: Int -> Int -> Int`.

Comment: @DominikTeiml correct. :) `(f . g) x = f (g x)`, `g (x::Int) :: Int -> Int`, `f :: Int -> Int`.  In general, for `g :: a -> b` and `f :: c -> d`, `f.g :: a -> d` with `b ~ c`. Here `g :: Int -> (Int -> Int)` (arrows in types associate to the right) and so it must be (for `f.g` to have a type) `(Int -> Int) ~ Int` which is not so.

Answer (score 0):

Function composition's initial definition is a bit confusing, so I'll write it a different way:

```
f . g = \a -> f (g a)
```

This means that `f . g` returns a function which first applies the argument to `g`, then applies the result of that to `f`. This is also clear in the type signature:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

Now for your function h, it has a type of something like `h :: a -> a -> a`. Remember that `->` is right-associative, so the type could be written as `h :: a -> (a -> a)`. Essentially, `h :: a -> b`, though this type would cause an error because `b` and `a` are uninferrable. `(.)` will only allow one argument to be applied to the first function, so:

```
-- One could write,
h x y = f (g x y)
-- But One could also write
h x = f . g x
-- Or, more clearly:
h x = (f) . (g x)
```

This is because Haskell functions are *curried*, so we can apply some arguments to `g` without fully evaluating it.

If we imagine what would happen if we applied `(.)` visually, then simplify, we can see how it works:

```
h x = \a -> f ((g x) a)
h x = \a -> f (g x a)
h x a = f (g x a)
```

So yes, b is the answer. This is because `(.)` only allows one argument to be applied to the first function before moving to the next.

Now you're job can be tackling the other incorrect solutions by simplifying as I have. It's not too difficult.